# i18n issue using servlet 3 and spring 3.2.3

Tags: spring, maven, internationalization, servlet-3.0, servlet-3.1

Im working with spring 3.2.3, servlet 3 and maven 3.1, so i'm trying to use i18n, but for some dark reason i can't start my app saying:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'login.button.signin' for locale 'pt_BR'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
```

but my default lang is "EN" and i have both properties with this message.

Code:

WebConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.codesenior.oaon.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en"));
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver templateResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setCache(false);
        return resolver;

    }
```

index.jsp

```
   <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <span style="float: right">
            <a href="?lang=en">en</a> 
            | 
            <a href="?lang=pt">pt</a>
        </span>
        <div class="login-form">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <form action="/login">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="clearfix">
                <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix">
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return signin();" value="<spring:message code="login.button.signin"/>" ></button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

messages (current path:src/main/resources)

messages_en.properties

```
login.label.username=Username
login.label.password=Password
login.button.signin=Signin
```

messages_pt.properties

```
login.label.username=Usuário
login.label.password=Senha
login.button.signin=Entrar
```

Since my default lang is EN, i don't know why it are asking for PT, although even if i ignore this point, i have messages_pt.properties that contains the correct message.

Full stacktrace:

```
2014-01-14 15:30:49 ERROR MessageTag:83 - No message found under code 'login.button.signin' for locale 'pt_BR'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'login.button.signin' for locale 'pt_BR'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Jan 14, 2014 3:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/checkpointweb] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp at line 86

83:               <div class="clearfix">
84:                 <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
85:               </div>
86:                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return signin();" value="<spring:message code="login.button.signin"/>" ></button>
87:             </fieldset>
88:           </form>
89:         </div>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'login.button.signin' for locale 'pt_BR'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Could you check what locale is returned by LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() ?

Comment: Thanks for reply JakubK
This method return: pt_BR
i have tried to change the file to messages_pt_BR.properties, but it still don't work.

Comment: Could you please paste whole stacktrace?